# Sqlite Android Database Connectivity Issue

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am creating a login page.

The problem is that my SQLite database is not allowing me to move to next page.
I have created two Classes

1. Contact
2. Database Helper

Now the Database Helper is giving error when I want to move further.
Any Help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

```
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

    public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSIO=1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="contacts.db";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME="contacts";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID="id";
    private static final String COLUMN_NAME="name";
    private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL="email";
    private static final String COLUMN_UNAME="uname";
    private static final String COLUMN_PASS="pass";

    SQLiteDatabase db;

    private static final String TABLE_CREATE="create table contacts(id integer  primary key not null auto_increment,"+
    "name text not null,email text not null,uname text not null,pass text not null);";


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSIO );
    }




    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
        this.db=db;

    }

    public void insertContact(Contact c){

        db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        String query="select * from contacts";
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query,null);

        int count=cursor.getCount();

        values.put(COLUMN_ID,count);
        values.put(COLUMN_NAME,c.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL,c.getEmail());
        values.put(COLUMN_UNAME,c.getName());
        values.put(COLUMN_PASS,c.getPass());

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
        db.close();
    }

    public String searchPass(String uname){

        db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        String query="select uname,pass from"+TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query,null);

        String a,b;
        b="not found";
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {

                a=cursor.getString(0);


                if (a.equals(uname))
                {
                    b=cursor.getString(1);
                    break;

                }

            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String query="DROP TABLE EXISTS"+TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL(query);
        this.onCreate(db);



    }
}
```

Comment: What does `SQLite database is not allowing me to move to next page` mean?

Comment: Can Please share your LogCat error